# How to show an action button in Facebook interface (web)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to put an action button or link associated with a FB post that will show up on any posts in someone's stream as they're reading their main page.

What I was thinking is a little link after the text of the post or a button in the action menu on each post, but any option that gives the user the ability to take an action for any individual post would work. I want someone to be able to copy the FB post's text into our database. This would give the user the ability to see certain posts they pick out of their feed in our application.

I can do this with a browser extension and have one written that does this, but I was wondering if there's a way with the FB API or FB Apps or something in the FB development tools ecosystem to do something like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can not execute any custom scripting in news feed. At most you could place a CTA on a post, but as far as I know those only allow you to link to some external URL.

Comment: @CBroe OK, that makes sense, and is kind of what I expected which is why I went the browser extension route. You mention Call To Action, can you point me in the direction of what you're referring to? I'd like to at least read more about that. I know back in the day (~10 years ago) I created a Facebook App that if installed by the user would show on their feed, but this particular app didn't connect to any individual posts and I'm not sure that app functionality is even there still.

Comment: Referring to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v14.0/page/feed#cta-spec regarding the CTA; although I am not sure if those still work outside of an ad context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited responses I'm getting here I'm going to say that this is not possible.